# loop in nested list in python

Tags: python, loops, nested

Hello I am new in Python and what I am trying to do is to make a loop in a nested list to sum the elements 10 by 10 in the code below:

1.1

```
for i in range (n):
            for k in range (n):
                G[i] += (F[(n*i)+k])
```

and I am getting the error:

> ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (6,)
>   (3,)

what I already did and worked was

1.2

```
for i in range (n):
    G[i]=F[n*i+0]+F[n*i+1]+F[n*i+2]+F[n*i+3]+F[n*i+4]+F[n*i+5]+F[n*i+6]+F[n*i+7]+F[n*i+8]+F[n*i+9]
```

So I am trying to do the loop to get the same as in 1.2 but I know i cant use the loop in 1.1 in python. How would I do that?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Make sure to set `G[i] = 0` before entering the second loop.

Comment: I did that, I just think the problem is with the += operand but I am not sure.

Comment: Please add the definitions of `G` and `F` as they are just before this code is executed, so we have something to reproduce.

Comment: n=10
t=[(0,0,0)]
F=t*n**2
G=t*n

Comment: Sorry, but the asterisks are getting in the way of writing this correctly. Please put the whole thing in backticks to avoid such formatting. If the code is like I think it is `n=10
t=[(0,0,0)]
F=t*n**2
G=t*n`, then I see no problem: https://repl.it/GQx8/7

Comment: Yes, the form is like this. I will try to find the problem then! Thanks a lot

Comment: Did you try the link to repl.it I just posted? Do you see it runs without errors? Can you provide a case where it produces the error? Did you use numpy arrays?

Comment: Yes i tried repl.it. I see that they change my list, where F was in the form F=[(0,0,0),(0,0,0),...] and G is in the form G=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0..] where i wanted to mantain the form [(0,0,0),(0,0,0),...].

Comment: Hmmm, it is the code that does it, not *they*. ;-) But what is your question now? It was about an error that seems related to numpy, but you show no code that relates to numpy. Anyway, my time is up. It will be for someone else to look at it.

Comment: I did use numpy and in my code the G is in the form {(0,0,0),(0,0,0)...} but i am not using the loop, I am using just the form 1.2.  When i try the loop it just go wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of what you want to add.
If it is a problem with the shape of the array, it should be

```
import numpy as np
n=10
t=[(0,0,0)]
F=np.array(t*n**2)
G=np.array(t*n)
for i in range (n):
    for k in range (n):
        G[i] += F[n*i+k]
```

Of course if t=[(0,0,0)], it sums up to zero

Comment: Yes! Thats my problem. I am still having some problem with the loop doing the sum right but thanks a lot!